# c# Access ObservableCollection as base

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I have a class with base an Observable collection. I am trying to set the Observablecollection from a List of items with the method clone as shown below:

```
   public class MyObservableCollection : ObservableCollection<Record> 
    {
        public void Clone(List<Record> originalEnityList) 
        {
            ObservableCollection<Record> cloned = new ObservableCollection<Record>(originalEnityList);
        }
    }
```

What i would like to do is to copy the cloned collection to the base ObservableCollection like:

```
    this=  new ObservableCollection<Record>(originalEnityList);
or
    this=cloned;
```

How can i do that?

I have tried the following without any progress:

1. ObservableCollection mine = this; mine=cloned;(While the mine collection is set the base collection remains empty).
2. I tried to do this from outside the class with no luck also,  like `MyObservableCollection coll =  new ObservableCollection<Record>(originalEnityList);` But i believe that MyObervableCollection is missing the new constructor that observablecollection has.

PS: I haved tried to use foreach and for to populate the collection but because my collection is really big, it takes too much time.

I am pretty sure that i am missing something really simple here.

Comment: "But i believe that MyObervableCollection is missing the new constructor that observablecollection has". Then why don't you add one?

Comment: In that case i would have to implement the new constructor from the observable collection like: 

public ObservableCollection(List<T> list);

But then the question would be how can i cast to  the  base object the list like 

public void Clone(List<Record> originalEnityList) 
        {
            ObservableCollection<Record> cloned = new ObservableCollection<Record>(originalEnityList);
//This cloned object should be casted or cloned to the base object
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add a constructor that takes the source collection as parameter:

```
public class MyObservableCollection : ObservableCollection<Record> 
{
    public MyObservableCollection()
    {
    }

    public MyObservableCollection(List<Record> originalEntityList)
        : base(originalEntityList)
    {
    }
}
```

With a static `Clone` methold like

```
private static List<Record> Clone(List<Record> originalEntityList)
{
    return ...
}
```

you could write the second constructor like this:

```
public MyObservableCollection(List<Record> originalEntityList)
    : base(Clone(originalEntityList))
{
}
```

Comment: You rock. I knew it would be something really simple(Sometimes the mind stops working properly). Thanks and vote up and accepted

Comment: @Panagiotis Eυχαρίστως

Comment: Να είσαι καλά αδερφέ για την βοήθεια(το μυαλλό κολάει εκεί που δεν το περιμένεις).